# How do I connect to an SQL Server 2017 server using web2py's data abstraction layer?

Tags: sql-server, web2py, sql-server-2017

Here is the last line from the debug trace:

> ".../Desktop/Web2PyProjects2/web2py/gluon/contrib/pypyodbc.py", line
>   966, in ctrl_err raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
>   gluon.contrib.pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('01000', "[01000]
>   [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not
>   found")

1. Cloned web2py from github.
2. Ran web2py from terminal: `$python3 web2py`
3. Created a fresh app from the web2py admin page.
4. Edit the file **appconfig.ini** using the web2py's web IDE. Made the following changes. Replaced this line, `uri=sqlite://storage.sqlite`, with this line, `mssql4://SA:123456@localhost/trellis_database`. As guided here: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Connection-strings-the-uri-parameter-
5. Reloaded the web2py app. Got the error message that is displayed above.
6. Tested the connection to the local server using Azure Data Studio.

Note that I'm running SQL Server 2017 in a Docker Container. We will eventually be pointing to our remote test/production server. I'm on a macOS Mojave machine, running python 3.7.